# Google log-in (with Firebase) suddenly stop working?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

My Google log-in function /w Firebase was working fine for days until it suddenly wont let me log in again after a sign out. It throws this exception:

```
04-28 23:28:17.639 1991-2393/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
                                                                          java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
                                                                              at evk.a(:com.google.android.gms:274)
                                                                              at evk.a(:com.google.android.gms:4238)
                                                                              at evk.a(:com.google.android.gms:170)
                                                                              at evj.a(:com.google.android.gms:63)
                                                                              at evh.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:58)
                                                                              at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                                                                              at bxp.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:35)
                                                                              at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
04-28 23:28:17.640 1991-2393/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
04-28 23:28:17.890 2371-4189/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [327] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=AIzaSyAdxh0yBc4QUZ4-CjcOn472ieduZiShkwY
04-28 23:28:17.894 2371-22212/com.google.android.gms I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: {
                                                                            "error": {
                                                                             "errors": [
                                                                              {
                                                                               "domain": "global",
                                                                               "reason": "invalid",
                                                                               "message": "Invalid id_token in IdP response: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImNmYWVjZjI5MWFhM2M4YWZiMDg2ZGUxYmU3ZGJlNmM3NjMyODI3NDYifQ.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.EyuUL2ONyko0VuwoRRxFcxCL1R6K3pYpDGx-poPa9jfj20jwALhg8aGArA_NZpg1qttTMagHrkfaaaNA2yvWZmy4nmvxoXKBHYRfjpatUstKd7GKcA28cJrONlM8ixEaI7Sie344jv53lLwbhpIb_OFjJWMVsQ3DoG9A-63nSliQC2LfAje2EcOaoDD7y3rDRKluRM18fmAijH6yKfR9PXNDKFOWDfWOC4XlXxuLvl18xUv8ExA-oZeHM8D_mF9p02ipEq_EyzQUwUzcVDjoJPeb_qDFjaHXZJ4KKD3pv30m8YP8LLQ6t_GXJwphwpqYVydGuIPHLsHz4Pmo-pP17w, error: Id_token failed validation."
                                                                              }
                                                                             ],
                                                                             "code": 400,
                                                                             "message": "Invalid id_token in IdP response: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImNmYWVjZjI5MWFhM2M4YWZiMDg2ZGUxYmU3ZGJlNmM3NjMyODI3NDYifQ.eyJhenAiOiIyMzA4MzIzMTgwMjQtdmM5am1udmRydTVzMGYyaXNldnM2cm8zdTA3Nm1vYmouYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiIyMzA4MzIzMTgwMjQtbTZuMDFpampnYWI5cjdpYmdlNmE3ODQ0M2xvYzRlNW8uYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiIxMTI5MTM1Mzg1MDg1MjY2MDU0MzciLCJlbWFpbCI6ImF2aWFtaXJzd2VAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTQ5MzQ2OTg0MSwiZXhwIjoxNDkzNDczNDQxLCJuYW1lIjoiQWxpIEFtaWQiLCJwaWN0dXJlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9saDQuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tLy1aZXVWdDZ6d1o4WS9BQUFBQUFBQUFBSS9BQUFBQUFBQUFBQS9BSGFsR2hxN2w5cW0xNlY4bDduZVNYdFdPMjlFSDVkLTVRL3M5Ni1jL3Bob3RvLmpwZyIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJBbGkiLCJmYW1pbHlfbmFtZSI6IkFtaWQiLCJsb2NhbGUiOiJlbiJ9.EyuUL2ONyko0VuwoRRxFcxCL1R6K3pYpDGx-poPa9jfj20jwALhg8aGArA_NZpg1qttTMagHrkfaaaNA2yvWZmy4nmvxoXKBHYRfjpatUstKd7GKcA28cJrONlM8ixEaI7Sie344jv53lLwbhpIb_OFjJWMVsQ3DoG9A-63nSliQC2LfAje2EcOaoDD7y3rDRKluRM18fmAijH6yKfR9PXNDKFOWDfWOC4XlXxuLvl18xUv8ExA-oZeHM8D_mF9p02ipEq_EyzQUwUzcVDjoJPeb_qDFjaHXZJ4KKD3pv30m8YP8LLQ6t_GXJwphwpqYVydGuIPHLsHz4Pmo-pP17w, error: Id_token failed validation."
                                                                            }
                                                                           }
04-28 23:28:17.897 22376-22376/com.appD/com.app.activity.SignInActivity: signInWithCredential:onComplete:false
04-28 23:28:17.897 22376-22376/com.appW/com.app.activity.SignInActivity: signInWithCredential
                                                                                                                    com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Invalid id_token in IdP response ]
                                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblv.zzce(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbls$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd.zzcf(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbly$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

**My code where I log out:**

```
//init google options
        if(gso != null){
            gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
        }
        if(mGoogleApiClient != null){
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();
        }

        //init sign out button and add an onclicklistener
        signOut = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
        signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Log out user from both FirebaseAuth and Google
                mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), SignInActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

**My code where I sign In:**

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = SignInActivity.class.getName();
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private SignInButton mSignInButton;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        // Assign fields
        mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        // Set click listeners
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();

        // Initialize FirebaseAuth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign-In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign-In failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign-In failed.");
            }
        }
    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGooogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

}
```

The sign in is from one activity, the sign out is from a fragment attached to another activity, if this information is somehow relevant.

It is in the method `firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct)` (In SignInActivity.java) where the authentication fails. Specifically, the `mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)` fails.

I don't know why this error occurred, anyone who knows why??

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase libraries were updated yesterday to 10.2.4:
https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

I updated my build.gradle file to get the Firebase library versions in sync with the Google Play Services versions:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
```

I'm not sure if it was necessary but I uninstalled my app from my emulator and deployed it freshly.

I do see the "Invalid device key response" error in my logging but the "Invalid id_token in IdP response" errors that I was seeing before making the build.gradle updates are now gone. And my users are logging in successfully.

Comment: updated to implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.3') and it worked

Answer (score 2):

ok first make sure you are using the latest verson of google play services. You can find the latest version [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). Next, you have to add this line to your application class `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` Let me know if it works.

Comment: This doesn't help in anyway